# Use JOIN in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, join, sequelize.js

prompt how to use JOIN in Sequelize ?
I have the following code:

```
        db.User.findAll({
        attributes: ['id'],
        where: {vipEnd: {lt: expiresVip}, vip: true},
        limit: 100,
        order: 'id'
    }).then(function(users) {
```

In terms of 4, it looks like this:

```
SELECT "vkId" AS "id" 
FROM "user" AS "user" 
WHERE "user"."vipEnd" < 1469699683 --expiresVip
AND "user"."vip" = true 
ORDER BY id 
LIMIT '100';
```

How to achieve such a result?

```
SELECT "vkId" AS "id" 
FROM "user" AS "user" 

LEFT JOIN "notification" ON "notification"."userId" = "user"."vkId"

WHERE "user"."vipEnd" < 1469699683
AND "user"."vip" = true 

AND "notification"."type" = 4
AND "notification"."expiresVipDate" < 1469699683

ORDER BY id 
LIMIT '100';
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to define association for models.
ex: 

`db.User.hasMany(db.Notification, {foreignKey: 'UserId'});`

use properties include in sequelize:

```
db.User.findAll({
include: [{
    model: db.Notification,
    required: true//true INNER JOIN, false LEFT OUTER JOIN - default LEFT OUTER JOIN
}]}).then(function(user) {}, function(err) {
res.json(err, 400);});
```

You should consult more here
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/